# UIImagePickerController issue?

Tags: objective-c, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

This is my code to present the UIImagePickerController:

```
// Show the media browser with our settings, then the browser will call our delegate if needed
- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    // Check for images type
    NSArray * availableTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
    BOOL imgsOnlyAvailable = NO;
    // Check if we have only images 
    for (int i = 0; i < [availableTypes count]; i++) {
        // Convert the type
        CFStringRef type = (CFStringRef) [availableTypes objectAtIndex:i];
        if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) type, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
            // We have images
            imgsOnlyAvailable = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Check if they are available
    if (imgsOnlyAvailable == NO) 
        return NO;

    // Displays only saved pictures from the Camera Roll album.
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(id) kUTTypeImage];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
    return YES;
}

// Picker delegate
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage;

    // Handle a still image picked from a photo album
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                     UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];    
        // Set image
        self.imgPic.image = originalImage;

        // Now set the button to enabled
        self.btnToText.enabled = YES;
    }

    // Hide picker selector
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

The problem is whenever I try to click an image in the UIImagePickerController nothing happens (usually it chooses the image then will dismiss the Controller)

Is there any reason why things are going wrong like this?

Thanks!

```
// Select the image
- (IBAction)btnSelectFileTouchUp:(id)sender {

    // Start the media browser
    if ([self startMediaBrowserFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self] == NO) {
        // Can't open the media browser
        UIAlertView * alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Can't open the photo media browser in this device" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alrt show];
        [alrt release];
    }
}
```

Comment: What object are you passing in as the `delegate` parameter `-startMediaBrowserFromViewController:usingDelegate:`?

Comment: I added the code look at the bottom.

Comment: Hm, is the `-imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method even being hit?

Comment: Are you having this problem on iOS 5? If so, it may be because you're using `parentViewController` instead of `presentingViewController`...

Comment: Yes this issue is only in iOS 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the documentation for `parentViewController` in the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW3). Specifically this little tidbit.

> Prior to iOS 5.0, if a view did not have a parent view controller and
>   was being presented modally, the view controller that was presenting
>   it would be returned. This is no longer the case. You can get the
>   presenting view controller using the presentingViewController
>   property.

In this instance, I expect that `parentViewController` is nil on iOS 5 and that is why the controller will not dismiss. Try replacing `parentViewController` with `presentingViewController`.

**Update:** You'll have to check for the existence of `presentingViewController` on `UIViewController` to provide behavior for iOS versions < 5.0.

```
UIViewController *dismissingController = nil;

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)])
    dismissingController = self.presentingViewController;
else
    dismissingController = self.parentViewController;

[dismissingController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Is this backwards compatible? If I use presentingViewController in iOS 4 will it work?

Comment: Thanks for this - `parentViewController` is still referenced on the [Apple UIImagePickerController docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406).

Comment: Ya that particular code snippet is out of date. I would file a bug report with Apple concerning it.